Chaincode installation failed in peer on Hyperledger fabric
I was making the java chain code which I packaged on ~/test-network folder with the name home.tar.gz but when I was installing the chaincode on peer0 of org1 by following the official documentation of fabric -> https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploy_chaincode.html#install-the-chaincode-package
it stuck and after a long time gave me error
" Error: chain code install failed with status: 500 - error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 2b0caf4392532efdcc5ddd517ee....: error sending: timeout expired while executing transaction.
I tried many times but it gives the same error.
This is an error happen while working on Linux Ubuntu.

As your question looks like, it might be possible there is a path issue with the chiancode code. checked all the 5 required paths again, or you can increase the timeout duration in the docker-compose.yaml file. Please check logs of peers like docker logs peer0.org1.example.com.
